# Loading a .raw gray scale image to a 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image

I am quite new to C++. I am trying to read a .raw image in C++ and store it in a 2D array for further modifications. I use the following code:

```
int dimX = 192;
int dimY = 256;
unsigned char bufferImage[256][192];
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen("D:\\T1MapAnalysis\\heartroi_Contour.raw", "r");
fread(&bufferImage[0][0], dimX,dimY , pFile);
```

The stored values in `bufferimage` are displayed as for example 
`bufferimage[114][67]='ÿ';` which should correspond to `255`.
When I want to check the following `bool` values

```
unsigned char val = bufferImage[114][67];
bool k = (val == 'ÿ')
bool k = (val == '255')
```

I get an error of different basic types.
I don't know how to compare `bufferImage` values to different gray scale values (0 to 255).
Thanks.

Comment: You probably wanted `255` without the single quotes. Also I'd be careful with characters like `'ÿ'` since they are outside the ascii range though that's probably just me being paranoid.

Comment: I'd advise to be careful with those characters too. Writing them in the program may have strange results. You should use `(unsigned char)255`, or `\xFF` if you prefer hex values.

Comment: The `ÿ` is not the character in your array, it's the glyph your terminal font uses to draw character number `xxx` onto the screen. Often times, when fonts don't have a glyph for a certain character, they fall back to something like `ÿ`. Otherwise, what Raphael said.